# Change ElasticSearch track_total_hits in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I was running thought examples of ElasticSearch, and read [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits) that says that there is a default set at 10,000, which also can be changed on the search calls, like on this example

```
GET twitter/_search
{
    "track_total_hits": 100,
     "query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : "Elasticsearch"
        }
     }
}
```

The problem is, I'm trying to do the same on NEST, but I don't manage to replicate it. The only thing similar that I found, only accept a Boolean value and not a number. It is possible to change the total through NEST?

Here is the code that I tried:

```cs
var results = elasticClient.Search<MyClass>(s => s
             .Query(q => q.QueryString(q2 => q2.Query(readLine)
             .Fields(f => f.Field(p => p.MyField)))).TrackTotalHits(true));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @russcam [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4241) at the moment you can do it via casting `ISearchRequest` to `IRequest<SearchRequestParameters>`:

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s =>
{
    IRequest<SearchRequestParameters> request = s;
    request.RequestParameters.SetQueryString("track_total_hits", 1000);
    
    return s;
});
```

It will apply it as querystring parameter